# FileSecurity vs DirectorySecurity in the .NET Framework

Tags: .net

Can someone **point out the specific differences between** the [DirectorySecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.directorysecurity.aspx) and the [FileSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesecurity.aspx) classes.

I know they both are implementations of the abstract [FileSystemSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemsecurity.aspx) class but to what extent do they actually differ?

As far as I can tell they are almost identical on the surface since they don't seem to be adding much in terms of public methods to the FileSystemSecurity class but then there must be some subtle differences.

The main reason I'm asking is because I'd like to copy permissions from a directory to some other objects which includes both directories and files.

Answer (score 2):

There are no convoluted rules here, they sound just like what they do.  The .NET framework code makes DirectorySecurity demands when you do something with a file system directory.  The System.IO.Directory and DirectoryInfo classes contain them.  And FileSecurity demands when you do something with a file.  Like in the System.IO.File, FileInfo and FileStream classes.

Comment: If it were just that then why create separate implementations of the FileSystemSecurity abstract class and not just one implementation?  There must be some differences - right?